# PHP round down rule

Tags: php

I found a bug in my code. Basically i was returning to the client the amount minus 1 cent and i found out that is due to int casting. Can someone explain why this is happening?

```
$x = 9.53 * 100;

var_dump($x); // double(953)
var_dump((int)$x); // int(952)
```

Moreover i discovered that this case is not occurring to all cases.
For example:

```
echo (int)(9.52 * 100)//952
echo (int)(9.53 * 100)//952
echo (int)(9.54 * 100)//953
echo (int)(9.55 * 100)//955
```

my solution to this problem is to first make the calculation and cast it string and the cast it to int and it seems to be working

Comment: Why don't you put simply echo (9.52 * 100). Or if you want to be sure that you don't get a decimal you just do the following echo round($calculation,0)?

Comment: I have not idea why it works like this, but just to be safe i usually stick to `bcmath`. Eg. `$result = bcmul(9.53 , 100);` (it returns string, but casting it to float does not break result)

Comment: @Arslan.H the point is to identify why it happens. Volvox is a similar solution to what i did to fix the issue. Toto displayed the reason it happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug, it's because of the representation of a floating number.

In memory, `9.53` is **not** exactly `9.53`, use [printf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) to see that:

```
$y = 9.53;
printf("%.25f\n", $y);
$x = 9.53 * 100;
printf("%.25f\n", $x);
```

**Output:**

```
9.5299999999999993605115378
952.9999999999998863131622784
```

Comment: I asumed it but you confirmed my assumption. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone explain why this is happening?

In computers, the real numbers are not stored exactly. They are approximations.

In real life, computing in base 10, `1/3` is `0.33333....`. One can never write it exactly, no matter how many `3` they put after the decimal digit. A rational number `m/n` has a finite representation as decimal ratio in base `10` if and only if the only prime factors of `n` are `2` and `5` (the prime factors of the base).

In computers everything is stored using base `2`. This means most of the numbers that have a finite representation in base `10` (as is `9.53`) does not have a finite representation in base `2` and an approximate value of them is actually stored instead.

Multiplying `9.53` by `100` doesn't help much. Due to the initial error, the result is an approximation of `953`. Because it is smaller than `953`, `(int)(9.53*100)` produces `952`.

Your situation is already documented in the PHP manual page about [integers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting.from-float):

> **Warning**
>
> Never cast an unknown fraction to [integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php), as this can sometimes lead to unexpected results.
>
> ```
>  <?php
>  echo (int) ( (0.1+0.7) * 10 ); // echoes 7!
>  ?>
> ```
>
> See also the [warning about float precision](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#warn.float-precision).

There are several solutions for this issue: you can use [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to get a string representation of the number without decimal digits then use [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) to get the integer value.

Another solution is to apply the `(int)` typecast on the value returned by [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) (but for some values it might not work).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Currently the solution to this issue was to make the calculation and cast it as a string and then cast it as an integer and return it to the function.  With some uni-tests and monitoring daily this temporary solution seems to do the trick.